# VM Join Domain and Connect to Internet

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm not really strong in networking and virtualization but I need to solve this case.

I have 4 servers in my VM with 1 of it as Domain Controller and 1 of it need to be connected to internet.

I tried some attempts:

**First**

```
In my server that need to be connected to internet, I put 2 Local Area Connection:

1 connection to join domain (Bridged) 
1 other to connect to internet (NAT)
```

**Second**

```
In Domain, I put 2 Local Area Connection:

1 connection for setting domain (Bridged)
1 other to connect to internet (NAT)
```

All says it is connected to internet but I can't access internet.
Can anyone advise me how to give internet to my server?

**Note:** I have turned off all firewall

Comment: LOL sorry. I forgot to set my proxt setting inside my VM